# Different (or preferred) ways of defaulting a value when GET parameter does not exist

Tags: php, syntax, default-value

This question is specifically for the reason of having neater code.

I am wondering what are all the different ways of defaulting a value, because I have an API controller which defaults all parameters that aren't being set, so I want to pick one that is prettiest and/or most intuitive.

Also, a question for more experienced programmers, what are the conventions or preferred ways of doing this?

A note for my case is that my variable names will not have the same name as the GET parameter value. Thus, in my example the `this_is_a_very_long_parameter_name` GET parameter is stored in the `$longParameterName` variable, and the `short` GET parameter is stored in the `$val` variable.

In my  example there are 2 variables, which in the real-world will be between 5 or 10 of them.

## 1

```
if(isset($_GET['short'])) {
    $val = $_GET['short'];
} else {
    $val = 'default1';
}

if(isset($_GET['this_is_a_very_long_parameter_name'])) {
    $longParameterName = $_GET['this_is_a_very_long_parameter_name'];
} else {
    $longParameterName = 'default2';
}
```

## 2

```
$val = 'default1';
if(isset($_GET['short'])) {
    $val = $_GET['short'];
}

$longParameterName = 'default2';
if(isset($_GET['this_is_a_very_long_parameter_name'])) {
    $longParameterName = $_GET['this_is_a_very_long_parameter_name'];
}
```

## 3

```
$val = (isset($_GET['short'])) ? $_GET['short'] : 'default1';
$longParameterName = (isset($_GET['this_is_a_very_long_parameter_name'])) ? $_GET['this_is_a_very_long_parameter_name'] : 'default2';
```

## 4

requires me to change the error-reporting setting :(

```
$val = $_GET['short'] ?: 'default1';
$longParameterName = $_GET['this_is_a_very_long_parameter_name'] ?: 'default2';
```

## 5

```
$val = 'default1';
$longParameterName = 'default2';

$parameters = [
    'short' => 'val', 
    'this_is_a_very_long_parameter_name' => 'longParameterName'
];
foreach($parameters as $getParam => $varName) {
    if((isset($_GET[$getParam]))) {
        $$varName = $_GET[$getParam];
    }
}
```

Comment: Second choice. Reasons-> easy to read, a bit faster, no scrolling

Comment: I guess this is a matter of preference. I use the second option most of the time.

Comment: I think first is much more readable, and takes only 1 more line than the option 2. Anyway, only options 1 and 2 are options... other ones are unreadable :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you will get to is what will happen if you have 10 variables? Your code will have 4X10 lines just of initializing those variables (and I'm not talking about the extra lines between each check to make sure your code is readable.

I would go with a dedicated function to do the work for you:

```
function get_or_default($var, $default) {
    if (isset($_GET[$var])) {
        return $_GET[$var];
    }
    return $default;
}

$val1 = get_or_default('val1', 'default1');
$val2 = get_or_default('val2', 'default2');
```

Comment: I already DO have 10 of them (sometimes even more, it turns out), I don't know if you were in time to catch my edit there. Which is why I absolutely love this approach, and I love you! Thanks man.

Comment: You are more than welcome :) Note that this way if you want to add some extra validation/verification/sanitizing it's really easy. If (for example) you don't want _GET values to be longer than 1000 chars it's very easy to do so, only 1 line of code and no need for duplication.